# Haskell list remove duplicates doesn't work completely correctly

Tags: haskell

I made this code for removing common elements in a list but it only worked for integers list i have an example for

```
remove [ A "List", A "List", A "Gone", A "Still"]
```

it must give as an output `[ A "List", A "Gone", A "Still"]`
it doesn't work gives an undefined constructor A

```
remove [] = []
remove (x:xs) | x `elem` xs = remove xs
              | otherwise = x : remove xs
```

Comment: Well syntax highlighting here already revelals one of the issues. But there are some other issues, for example, it can not process an infinite list at all (unless it only contains duplicates, but then it will keep searching for the first non-duplicate).

Comment: What is `A` supposed to be here? Of course the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about, if `A` isn't defined!

Comment: Then how can I edit the code if i want it to work for a list like the one above

Comment: @IslamNasr Define `A`, or remove it. I don't know what you want it to be, but you probably want this line: `data A = A String deriving (Eq, Show)`.

Comment: @AJFarmer ill try it now

Comment: @IslamNasr You still haven't answered  though - what is `A` meant to be?

Comment: It is a letter the project description didn't specify what is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is not per se the function itself, but the input list:

```
remove [ A "List", A "List", A "Gone", A "Still"]
```

It contains a list of elements, each element has the *data constructor* `A` followed by a string. In some languages like Prolog, one can dynamically introduce functors, but not in Haskell: Haskell is statically typed, and as a result you need to declare the types. We can for instance declare the type:

```
data A = A String deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now we declared a type `A`, where there is a single data constructor `A` that takes as parameter a `String`. We made it `deriving (Eq, Show)`, such that two `A`s are equal, given they have the same data constructor (but since there is only one, this is always the case), as well as the fact that the parameter should be the same. The `Show` enables us to print `A` instances.

So now it will at least produce output (not generate a compiler error). But the function itself still has a potential problem: here you check membership in the *tail* of ther list. There can be two problems with that:

1. we will always keep the *last* occurrence, so `remove [1, 4, 1, 2]` will return `[4, 1, 2]`, whereas we probably want to return `[1, 4, 2]`; and
2. in case we process an infinite list, then for non-duplicate elements, `elem`, will keep looking for a duplicate. As a result eventually Haskell will run out of memory and crash.

We better use an accumulator here that stores the elements thus far observed, and call `elem` on that list, like:

```
remove :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
remove = go []
    where go _ [] = []
          go seen (x:xs) | elem x seen = go seen xs
                         | otherwise = x : go (x:seen) xs
```